# Finance vs Finances, what's different?

Tags: grammar

I confuse between finance vs finances, which word should I use for a domain such as mexicofinances.com or mexicofinance.com? What is different and which is right?

Any explanation?

Comment: Did you look this up in a dictionary? A good dictionary will tell you the answer.

Comment: @Laurel I do, I have been searching in Oxford Dictionary recently but I still don't understand.

Comment: I can't found finances, only finance but I still found some websites use finances in their article.

Comment: Include what you found in your question (ideally this should be done before posting :P).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finance refers to the field itself, e.g. I studied finance during my business degree, I work in finance.

Finances is used when referring to an individual or organisation's financial management/arrangements.